# recursive update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just created a column call UPDATE on my table, and I would like to fill it according to my data.

Every time an object as been change from the primary key (ID,YEAR) I would like to update the column UPDATE

```
||      ID      ||      YEAR        ||      OBJECT      ||      UPDATE
    1               2010                  1                 2010
    2               2010                  2                 2010
    3               2011                  3                 2011
    1               2011                  1                 2010
    2               2011                  1                 2011
    3               2011                  1                 2011
```

I don't know how many queries I have and years. But I only have few OBJECT

I would appreciate your help on that

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your question?

Comment: Why do you need the column `update` for?

Comment: I don't even know how to start. And I would like to udpate with a script the collumn UPDATE.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Do you want to perform an `UPDATE` operation that fills in `[UPDATE]` field values of *all* rows?

Comment: Start here:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: What makes this recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you provided, this is the SQL that should provide the UPDATE column as shown in the question.

```
UPDATE t
SET UPDATE=ISNULL(minyear.[MinYear],Year)
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID,OBJECT,MIN(YEAR) [MinYear]
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ID,OBJECT
) minyear on minyear.ID=t.ID
    AND minyear.OBJECT=t.OBJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using SQL Server 2012+ then you can use `LAG` to get *previous* value:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT ID, YEAR, OBJECT, [UPDATE], 
          COALESCE(LAG(YEAR) OVER (PARTITION BY OBJECT 
                                   ORDER BY YEAR, ID), 
                   YEAR) AS prevYear 
   FROM mytable
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET [UPDATE] = prevYear
```

Updates performed on the `CTE` are propagated to the real DB table. Hence, the `UPDATE` operation fills in `[UPDATE]` field with the value of the previous record.

Note: `LAG` fetches the value of `YEAR` of the *previous* row, as defined by `ORDER BY YEAR, ID` clause. In case there is no previous value, then `[UPDATE]` is set equal to `YEAR` value of the same record.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90cde/1)